# find pairs in int [] b;?

Tags: java, arrays

how to find all pairs of numbers chosen from b, 
for example i have

```
int [] b = {1,2,3,5,4,3,2,1,1};
```

and i need to print the pairs found in this integer array and the position they are at
keep in mind that i tried to compare them like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < ia.length; i++) {
    number = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < ia.length; j++) {
        if (ia[i] == ia[j]) {
            number++;
        }
    }
    if (number%2==0) {
        System.out.println("found pairs at  ia["+i+"] = "+ia[i] );
    }
}
```

but the problem is that it keeps comparing the other numbers so if we have a number that can be found 3 times  the first time it will compare it and will say that it's not a pair but the second time it will not be compared with previous value so instead of 3 it will find 2 and it will say that it's pair

thank you for taking time in responding to my question

Comment: This code does not compare anything since it does not compile.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to achieve

Comment: What is your wanted output given this input?

Comment: so i must found the pairs in b 
for example int []b={1,2,1,2,2}
it must say that 1 is pairs
while 2 is not

Comment: all the digits which appear twice in the list?

Comment: ... and what do you mean by "pair"?

Comment: yes exactly  .....

Comment: all the digits which appear twice in the list

Comment: you have to test for `i!=j`, otherwise everything will be pair, with itself.

Comment: You can't have an `else if` just appearing out of nowhere without a previous `if`. And if the array is called `b`, why is it `ia` in your code? Please [edit] your question and put the **real** code in it. Make sure you format it properly.

Comment: yes i made a mistake it was if before it and i forget to delete else

Answer (score 0):

You have a few errors in there, here you go:

```
int[]ia={1,2,1,2,2};
        for (int i = 0; i < ia.length; i++) {
            int number = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < ia.length; j++) {
                if (ia[i] == ia[j]) {
                    number++;
                }
            }
            if (number%2==0) {
                System.out.println("found pairs at  ia["+i+"] = "+ia[i] );
            }
        }
```

Everyone starded somewhere....

Comment: yes i told that it was if before the else and i deleted the if and forget the else

Comment: note: it writes that 1 is a pair 2x, this can be fixed by replacing j=0 with j=i

Comment: @MrRedstoner: Your program printing three occurrences of a number as a pair when put j=i.  That is in your example ia={1,2,1,2,2};, 2 is also printed in pair while it should not be. Otherwise its corrrect

Comment: it prints position 2, which is where the second 1 is

Comment: @MrRedstoner: I mean to say your program works correct when j=0 and not when j=i.

Comment: oh sorry, never tested that part... you are right, my bad

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<Integer, Integer> counter = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
for(int i:b){
if(counter.get(i)!=null)
   counter.put(i,1);
else
   counter.put(i,counter.get(i)+1);
}
//Print all with values two or completely divisible by 2 if required
for(int i:counter.keySet()){
 if(counter.get(i)%2==0)
  System.out.println("Pair number: "+i);
}
```

Sorry if there are any compilation errors. I just wrote the code in browser.

Comment: thank you for your answer but i must use int [] ia;
not array list

Comment: There is no limitation that this code will be used with ArrayList. It works perfectly fine with int[] :) Even the usage of Map would give you better time and space complexity with no size limitations

Answer (score 0):

No need to go overly complicated here. For a simple case such as yours, without using `List` or `Map`, we can do it like this:

```
int [] numbers = {1,2,3,5,4,3,2,1,1};
int [] used = new int[numbers.length];
for(int digit : numbers) used[digit] += 1;

//At this point all entries in used with a value of 2 match
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(used));
```

Which will output `[0, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]`, meaning the digit 0 was found 0 times, the digit 1 was found 3 times, the digit 2 was found 2 times, etc. Just don't do this if your numbers are huge, or the list is huge, I'm assuming you're learning the basics here.

Comment: what if we have the length equal to 100